# OpenGL Redbook example 1.1 fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, compiler-errors

So I have the first code example out of the new opengl redbook and it will not compile. 
At first it was because it was saying `LoadShaders.cpp` wasn't there or something and I fixed that but now it says `fatal error LNK1169`: one or more multiply defined symbols found. And there's like a million errors saying stuff is already defined in `MSVCRTD.lib`. Here's the log:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: legit, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>libcmtd.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __CrtSetCheckCount already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>libcmtd.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>libcmtd.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>libcmtd.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>libcmtd.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>libcmtd.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>libcmtd.lib(_fpinit_.obj) : error LNK2005: __fltused already defined in a previous module
1>libcmtd.lib(_fpinit_.obj) : error LNK2005: __ldused already defined in a previous module
1>libcmtd.lib(dbghook.obj) : error LNK2005: __crt_debugger_hook already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>libcmtd.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>libcmtd.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>libcmtd.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>libcmtd.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>libcmtd.lib(hooks.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>libcmtd.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>libcmtd.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>libcmtd.lib(winxfltr.obj) : error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>libcmtd.lib(setlocal.obj) : error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>libcmtd.lib(crt0.obj) : error LNK2005: _mainCRTStartup already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>libcmtd.lib(errmode.obj) : error LNK2005: ___set_app_type already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>libcmtd.lib(dbgrptw.obj) : error LNK2005: __CrtDbgReportW already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj) : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'libcmtd.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>C:\Users\Cole\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\legit\Debug\legit.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

As you can see, mostly all of it is from `MSVCRTD.lib` I think. project: My `main.cpp` is exactly how it is in the book so I don`t know what to do. Tell me what you think please?

Comment: Hard to be sure how, but somehow, you're linking both the dynamic and static run-time libraries. This is almost certainly a problem with how you're building the code, not with the code itself.

Comment: I added the includes and libs into the actual vsc++ folders and linked  them in the linker, could that cause the problems? or am isupposed to do that?

Comment: Yes, that's almost certainly the problem. Libcmt[d] or msvcrt[d] will be linked by default, so you don't need to link them explicitly. You'll probably need to link user32.lib, kernel32.lib, gdi32.lib and opengl32.lib. If you get undefined references, look them up, and add libraries specifically for them (but blindly adding all libs leads to problems, as you've already found).

Comment: So im not allowed to just put all the lib files provided from the book into the vsc++ lib folder, or link them in additional library directory's?  which one should i do?

Comment: The libs from the book should go in a separate folder. Not sure which you should link to though.

Comment: Oh alright thank you i will take out the libs i put in the lib folders and start a new project. should i do the same for the provided header files?

Comment: i just tried it and it gives me the same errors :(

Comment: Make sure the third-party libraries you are using are built with the same Runtime Library options as your project in Visual Studio. Most of the time, msvcrt[d] is used in third-party libraries so your project has to link to msvcrt[d]. If you are unsure what I am saying here, list out all the .lib files that you are linking to your project so we can at least guess which might be the culprit.

Comment: In your project properties, what is your setting for `Configuration Properties`/`C/C++`/`Code Generation`/`Runtime Library`?  You probably want it to be dynamically linked (`/MD` or `/MDd`).  Statically linking your runtime is possible if all your libraries were compiled that way as well, but it's more problematic.  Each library uses its own copy of the runtime, with its own heap, so objects must always be destroyed using the same runtime that created them.  Not to mention it bloats your executable.